# Guacamole only listening on IPv6 localhost

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, tomcat, ipv6

I have recently installed Apache Guacamole on Ubuntu 20.04 and also tested with the same result on 21.10. I have it all working but have had to do some workarounds because of this issue.

Here is the [guide](https://ciphermenial.github.io/guacamole-with-sql-and-2fa/) I created after I had completed my install and figured out all the issues.

My question is around whether anyone knows of a way to make guacd listen on both IPv4 and v6? My work around was orginally to disable IPv6 on the server but that needs to be run on each startup. I then discovered I could change the listening address to 127.0.0.1 and it would listen on IPv4 instead of v6. I know this is probably the fix but I don't understand why I can't make guacd listen on both.

Comment: Per that link, "I had to set guacd-hostname to 127.0.0.1 because otherwise it would listen on IPv6 only and failed to work."  What exactly is the problem?  "failed to work" is not a helpful problem description.  Why do you need dual stack?  Just ::1 is fine for localhost.  Also, please don't rely on external links for your question details, copy relevant details into your question.

Comment: If it listens on ::1 you must manually set the Guacamole Proxy Parameters for every connection you create to point to ::1. If you have it listen on 127.0.0.1 you don't require any modification to that part of the config as it is the default. I don't understand why it can't listen universally on localhost and include ipv4 and v6.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not asking for a workaround, but the full background:

1. Check what addresses your bind_host (ie. "localhost") resolves to:

```
$ python3 -c "import socket
print(set([a[4][0] for a in socket.getaddrinfo('localhost', 4822)]))"

{'127.0.0.1', '::1'}
```

2. Possibly open a new issue for guacd to properly implement support for dual-stack IPv4/IPv6 and allow specifying a bind_host which has multiple different addresses.

I did some work fixing IPv6-only support in guacd https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GUACAMOLE-1190 which was sufficient for my purposes.

Supporting proper IPv6 dual-stack in any TCP server, while also allowing the user to restrict binding to specific addresses means:

- Create multiple sockets
- `bind()` to all addresses returned by `getaddrinfo()` (127.0.0.1 and ::1 for "localhost")
- `listen()` on all successfully bound sockets
- Use `select()` or `poll()` to react to incomming clients on all bound sockets at once
- Call `accept()` to accept a client connection after `select()` returns without error for a certain socket in the set

For reference see these answers/sites:

[Semantics of :: and 0.0.0.0 in dual-stack OSes](https://serverfault.com/a/39561)

[How to support both IPv4 and IPv6 connections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1618259/13039183)

[select - synchronous I/O multiplexing](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/select.html)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is still a high search result for the issue, guacamole 1.4 has moved the config location.

https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/configuring-guacamole.html#configuring-guacd

So adding `/etc/guacamole/guacd.conf`

```
[server]

bind_host = 127.0.0.1
bind_port = 4822
```

Or other bind hosts will get back the ipv4 behaviour.